# Enum.each loses variable when looping over an ExUnit test

Tags: elixir, ex-unit

When running the following code I get the warning:

```
warning: variable "char" does not exist and is being expanded to "char()", please use parentheses to remove the ambiguity or change the variable name
  test/my_module_test.exs:7
```

Followed by a failed test:

```
== Compilation error in file test/my_module_test.exs ==
** (CompileError) test/my_module_test.exs:7: undefined function char/0
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1338: :lists.foreach/2
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:680: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
    (elixir) lib/code.ex:767: Code.require_file/2
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:209: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_workers/6
```

```rb
defmodule MyModule do
  use ExUnit.Case, async: true
  doctest MyModule

  Enum.each ~w(a b c), fn char ->
    test "test involving #{char}" do
      assert char == char
    end
  end
end
```

It seems that within the `Enum.each` block the value of `char` is defined for the line `test "... #{char}" do` but becomes undefined within the assertions.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`ExUnit.test/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_unit/ExUnit.Case.html#test/3) is [a macro](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.8.2/lib/ex_unit/lib/ex_unit/case.ex#L270) that defines a function for you.

Every time you define a new function in Elixir, it starts a new scope. This means any variable defined outside of the function won't be available inside the function. For example, you can't do this:

```
foo = 1
def some_function() do
  foo
end
```

There are some ways you can bypass this mechanism. One is to use `unquote` to inject some values as AST. However, in this case, the simplest approach is to put the value in a module attribute, so you can read it inside the function:

```
@foo 1
def some_function() do
  @foo
end
```

---

Whether you want to run the same test with different inputs (although it likely means there are issues with the test structure design,) you might use [`ExUnit.Callbacks.setup_all/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_unit/ExUnit.Callbacks.html?#setup_all/2) to setup tests context, or use module attributes as shown in the documentation for [`ExUnit.Case.test/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_unit/ExUnit.Case.html?#test/3)

```
Enum.each ~w(a b c), fn char ->
  @char char
  test "test involving #{char}", ctx do
    assert @char == @char
  end
end
```

Module attributes are obviously visible from anywhere in a module after they are defined.